# Iterating through a boost::dynamic_bitset

Tags: c++, boost

I have a [boost dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) that I am trying to extract the set bits from:

```
boost::dynamic_bitset<unsigned long> myBitset(1000);
```

My first thought was to do a simple 'dump' loop through each index and ask if it was set:

```
for(size_t index = 0 ; index < 1000 ; ++index)
{
   if(myBitset.test(index))
   {
      /* do something */
   }
}
```

But then I saw two interesting methods, `find_first()` and `find_next()` that I thought for sure were meant for this purpose:

```
size_t index = myBitset.find_first();
while(index != boost::dynamic_bitset::npos)
{
        /* do something */
        index = myBitset.find_next(index);
}
```

I ran some tests and it seems like the second method is more efficient, but this concerns me that there might be another 'more correct' way to perform this iteration.  I wasn't able to find any examples or notes in the documentation indicating the correct way to iterate over the set bits.

So, is using `find_first()` and `find_next()` the best way to iterate over a `dynamic_bitset`, or is there another way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`find_first` and `find_next` are the fastest way. The reason is that these can skip over an entire block (of `dynamic_bitset::bits_per_block` bits, probably 32 or 64) if none of them are set.

Note that `dynamic_bitset` [does not have iterators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#rationale), so it will behave a bit un-C++'ish no matter what.

Comment: @Iarsmans: Thanks.  Without an example about it, I thought maybe there was an even better way, but with your explanation we can't really expect much better than that.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your definition of *more correct*. A correct method probably must yield correct results on all valid inputs and be fast enough.

`find_first` and `find_next` are there so that they can be optimized to scan entire blocks of bits in one comparison. If a block is, say, an unsigned long of 64 bits, one block comparison analyses 64 bits at once, where a straightforward loop like you posted would do 64 iterations for that.